# Can an Application token be used instead of a Personal Access Token for github/checkout?

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that's using [github/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) and I'm trying to use a Github Application so I can give it higher permissions when it's pushing to a repository. When I added that token in the usual way:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      token: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

it failed with

> could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

which I think just means the token is invalid, but I'm not 100% sure. Is this possible? How should it be done?

Comment: It is not everyday I put an answer to someone who registered to Stack Overflow *before* I did :)

Comment: @VonC just by one day... those days at the very beginning were a lot of fun, with the podcast and the fresh site. I miss that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will need to generate the right token (an [installation token](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-an-installation-access-token-for-a-github-app)): then one you are using prompts GitHub to query credentials which, in a non-interactive context, fails with the error message you see.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_APP_INSTALLATION_TOKEN }}
```

Register as a secret you app installation token created with:

```bash
curl --request POST \
--url "https://api.github.com/app/installations/INSTALLATION_ID/access_tokens" \
--header "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer JWT" \
--header "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
```

Note: The installation access token will expire after 1 hour, so you would need to generate a new one each time you run your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot checkout using `GITHUB_TOKEN` since it is scoped to a particular repo. You might need to create a GitHub PAT ([link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)).

You can find the related GitHub issue discussion about this [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/799#issuecomment-1242044502)